# SQL query not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a table in a mySQL database used for recording Fantasy Football (soccer) data. The table records how many points were earned each week as well as which players were selected as the captain and vice captain. The captain and vice captain columns link to a 'players' table via a unique ID.

e.g. `512 = David Beckham, 112 = Cristiano Ronaldo`

When I run the following query in my SQL client it executes perfectly, bringing back the player names associated with the unique ID:

```
    select 
        g.id, 
        g.season, 
        g.year, 
        g.points_gross, 
        g.points_net, 
        g.trans_available,      
        g.trans_made, 
        g.wildcard, 
        g.month, 
        cap.name, 
        vice.name
    from 
        gameweeks g
    inner join 
        players cap
    on 
        cap.id = g.captain
    inner join 
        players vice
    on 
        vice.id = g.v_captain

    where 
        g.id in ('1','2','3','4')
```

However, when I execute the same query via a simple PHP page that I made, it returns the table but leaves the player names blank.

I am even echoing the SQL query to the PHP page in order to troubleshoot and it matches the SQL query run in the client perfectly.

Comment: Can you post the php up as well?

Comment: Sounds like the mapping to php code is missing or wrong. Can you please post the code too?

Comment: where's your php code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use alias for the selected column

```
cap.name as player_name
```

And in PHP end you need to use the index `player_name` to get the data.

The reason is you have 2 name selections

`cap.name, vice.name`

And to get the name from players you need to use alias as shown

Answer (score 0):

```
  select g.id, g.season, g.year, g.points_gross, g.points_net, g.trans_available,      
    g.trans_made, g.wildcard, g.month, cap.name as captain_name, vice.name as vice_cap_name
    from gameweeks g
    inner join players cap
    on cap.id = g.captain
    inner join players vice
    on vice.id = g.v_captain
    where g.id in ('1','2','3','4')
```

you ware return to same value as name .

please using as then name like cap_name and vice_cap_name. 
hope it will work . 
Thanks